# Similar questions scroll sticky/overlap

Tags: bug, design, scrolling, similar-questions

On the Ask A Question page, the Similar Questions sometimes has a visual bug that the initially displayed content remains in place when scrolling, and the scrolled content is superimposed.  Examples (Firefox 70.0.1 64-bit on Windows 10):

[image: Screenshot of "similar questions" box with superimposed content]
[image: Another screenshot, from this question]

I can't quite nail down the specific conditions that cause this to occur, but it might have something to do with clicking away from the Ask A Question page and then clicking back to it.